# Change/rename Drupal 7 overlay tabs

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, overlays

I am having a task where I should change overlay tabs the way it appears/ rename the tabs that appears on a node edit (please have a look on this screenshot http://bit.ly/VIMMXK)

1. I should not have the "Edit" on the overlay
2. The "view" should be renamed to "View (content-type)"

Answer (score 0):

[Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module lets you change the name of different tabs on the drupal site. It also allows to to disable or hide tabs.